# django create random url valid id sequence for objects

Tags: django, url

I want to create a more ore less short think youtube url codes (watch=dQw4w9WgXcQ), which contain all URL legal characters to use as an id for my objects.
Is there a library that allows me to do this? Basicly instead of using a consecutive number to identify and object, use a random sequence.
I know theres a UUID libarary, but 16 bytes just seams to long, I would like to keep my URLs a bit shorter.
So whats is the best way to do this?

Comment: Look in the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) library, you should find a way to generate random strings. Also make sure to check for duplicates before saving the object. With a short length string you increase the chances of a collision.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/url-shortening-hashes-in-practice/

Comment: What are the constraints for this short string? Are you saving it in the db as part of the model? Or do you want to reconstruct the original `id` from the string itself? Should it be secure (ie impossible for a someone with the string to reconstruct the `id`)?

Comment: no it should be used as the id of object, just like a primary key